# How to comment on a post in facebook3.1 using graph api in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook 3.1 and try comment on a particular post. I have used the following code. I have used the below mentioned permissions also while creating session:

```
read_stream,offline_access,publish_stream,share_item
```

The code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is my comment", @"message", nil];
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/153125724720582_184234384932460/comments?access_token=%@",appDelegate.session.accessToken];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:string
                     parameters:params
                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                       id result,
                       NSError *error) {
                         if (error) {
                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                         } else {
                           NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                         }
}];

Response  : 
Result: {
    comments = 1;
    id = "https://graph.facebook.com/153125724720582_184234384932460/comments";
}
```

But my message is not updated on commented post id.

Same code with Post request also I have tried but Response is:

```
Result: {
    "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an HTTP POST and make sure that the user has granted `publish_stream` permissions.

You should copy and paste the API call (and the access token) into the Graph Explorer to test your call out.

(Also use the access_token debugger to make sure the permission is there)

Comment: Hi James Pearce,Thanks for giving reply by using Graph explorer i am able to comment on a post but in my code the result is "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = false; can you help me on this

Comment: @SrikanthGto please post the debugger output for the access token that the code is using

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation finally i got it

Comment: Glad to hear. Was it that in the end?

Comment: using this URL getting successful responce

Comment: /153125724720582_184234384932460/comments?access_token=%@",appDelegate.session.accessToken

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test Comment", @"message", nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"153125724720582_184234384932460/comments"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (error)
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          else
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                      }];
```

Comment: @MitsB Yea, I know because Facebook changed all the SDK, that's since 2013 :)